# BeautifulSoup - Element only showing first result multiple times

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape football match data from the following URL:

https://liveonsat.com/uk-england-all-football.php

I am able to scrape the match names, start times and channel names correctly. Unfortunately I seem to be having an issue scraping the correct match date. I have identified with help from stackoverflow previously that the element containing the match date can be called with

```
parent.find
```

The issue I am having though is that the first date that is scraped persists throughout all the matches that are scraped even if a particular game is not on that date. For instance if I run the code today it is showing the match date for all matches as Saturday 11th July, even though some of the matches that are scraped are on different dates.

I am unsure at this point what the problem could be and would be extremely grateful if someone could assist me or point me in the right direction to attempt to solve this issue. I was first thinking that the problem was with the HTML element that was selected to grab the match date from but I have changed this to previous parent elements to test and no date is scraped at all, so it appears the element currently selected to gather match date is correct, but it is possible not implemented correctly by me.

To help I have left a comment beside the match date element which I am having the issue with.

```
import requests
import time
import csv
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


def makesoup(url):
    page=requests.get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
   
    
    
def matchscrape(g_data):
    for match in g_data:
    
        competitors = match.find('div', class_='fix').text
        match_date = match.parent.find('h2',class_='time_head').text # this is used to scrape the match date as it is not contained within "div", {"class": "blockfix"}))

        match_time = match.find('div',class_='fLeft_time_live').text.strip()
        print("Competitors ", competitors) 
        print("Match date", match_date)
        print("Match time", match_time)
            
    #Match time
        channel = match.find_all("td", {"class": "chan_col"})
        for i in channel:
                print(i.get_text().strip())
        
            
            
def matches():
    soup=makesoup(url = "https://liveonsat.com/uk-england-all-football.php")
    matchscrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "blockfix"}))

    
        
        
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geomAetry("600x600")
root.wm_title("liveonsat scraper")
Label = tk.Label(root, text = 'liveonsat scraper', font = ('Comic Sans MS',18))
button = tk.Button(root, text="Scrape Matches", command=matches)
button3 = tk.Button(root,  text = "Quit Program", command=quit)
Label.pack()
button.pack()
button3.pack()
status_label = tk.Label(text="")
status_label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Below is the relevant example HTML code of the site I am scraping:

```
<div style="clear:right">    <div class=floatAndClearL><h2 class = sport_head >Football</h2></div>  <!-- sport_head -->
    <div class=floatAndClearL><h2 class = time_head>Saturday, 11th  July</h2></div> <!-- time_head -->         <div><span class = comp_head>English Championship - Week 43</span></div>
       <div class = blockfix >                <!-- block 1-->
    <div class=fix>                 <!-- around fixture and notes 2-->
          <div class=fix_text>               <!-- around fixture text 3-->
              <div class = imgCenter><span><img src="../img/team/england.gif"></span></div>
              <div class = fLeft style="width:270px;text-align:center;background-color:#ffd379;color:#800000;font-size:10pt;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif">Derby County v Brentford</div>
              <div class = imgCenter><img src="../img/team/england.gif"></div>
    </div>                  <!-- around fixture text 3 ENDS-->
        <div class=notes></div>
     </div>                  <!-- around fixture and notes 2 ENDS-->

            <div class = fLeft>                <!-- around all of channel types 2-->     <div>             <!-- around channel type group 3-->
       <div class=fLeft_icon_live_l>       <!-- around icon 4-->
         <img src="../img/icon/live3.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class=fLeft_time_live>       <!-- around icon 4-->
         ST: 12:30
       </div>           <!-- around icon 4 ENDS-->        <div class = fLeft_live>       <!-- around all tables of a channel type 4-->       <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class=chan_col>&nbsp; <a href="https://connect.bein.net/" target="_blank"  class = chan_live_iptvcable>              beIN Connect MENA </a></td><td width = 0></td>
                    </tr></table>       <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class=chan_col>&nbsp; <a href="https://tr.beinsports.com/kullanici/giris?ReturnUrl=" target="_blank"  class = chan_live_iptvcable>              beIN Connect TURKEY </a></td><td width = 0></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `find.parent` use `.find_previous()`, because `parent` is common (and thus the same) for all `<div class="blockfix">`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://liveonsat.com/uk-england-all-football.php'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')


for match in soup.select('div.blockfix'):
    competitors = match.find('div', class_='fix').text.strip()
    match_date = match.find_previous('h2', class_='time_head').text.strip() # <-- use .find_previous()
    match_time = match.find('div',class_='fLeft_time_live').text.strip()
    channels = match.select('.chan_col')
    print("Competitors ", competitors)
    print("Match date", match_date)
    print("Match time", match_time)
    print('Channels:\n\t' + '\n\t'.join(c.get_text(strip=True) for c in channels))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Competitors  Derby County v Brentford
Match date Saturday, 11th  July
Match time ST: 13:30
Channels:
    beIN Connect MENA ðŸ“º
    beIN Connect TURKEY ðŸ“º
    beIN Sports MENA 5 HD
    beIN Sports Turkey 4 HD
    Eleven Sports 1 Portugal HD
    Nova Sport (serbia) HD
    Nova Sports 1 HD (Cyprus)
    Nova Sports 1 HD (Hellas)
    Sky Sports Football UK / HD
    Sport 4 Israel / HD
    Sportdigital TV HD
    SportsMax 2 HD
    StÃ¶d 2 Sport 2 / HD
    SuperSport 9 RSA
    Telekanal Futbol
    TV3 Sport HD Sweden
    V Sport 1 HD (norge)
    V Sport Extra HD (sweden)
    ViaPlay (denmark) / HD
    ViaPlay (finland) / HD
    ViaPlay (norway) / HD
    ViaPlay (sweden) / HD
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Competitors  Watford v Newcastle United
Match date Saturday, 11th  July
Match time ST: 13:30
Channels:
    Amazon Prime UK Only [$]
    beIN Connect MENA ðŸ“º
    beIN Sports MENA 12 HD
    beIN Sports MENA 2 HD
    Belarus 5 TV
    Canal+ Now HD (poland)
    Cosmote Sport 7 HD
    Cytavision Sports 1 HD
    DAZN Canada [$] (geo/R)
    DAZN EspaÃ±a [$] (geo/R)
    Diema Sport 2 HD
    ESPN Brasil HD
    EuroSport 1 Romania / HD
    Premier Sports 1 HD (ROI only)
    QazSport / HD
    RMC Sport 2 HD
    Setanta Qazaqstan HD
    Setanta Sports Ukraine+ HD
    Sky Sport 1 / HD Germany
    Sky Sport Arena Italia / HD
    Sky Sport Austria 1 HD
    Sky Sport Football Italia / HD
    Sport 2 Israel / HD
    Sport TV2 (portugal) / HD
    SportKlub 2 (serbia) HD
    SpÃ­ler 1 TV / HD
    SuperSport 4 RSA / HD
    TRT Spor / HD ðŸ“º
    TSN Malta 2 HD
    TV2 Sport Premium 2 HD
    TV2sumo.no [$] (geo/R)
    TV3 MAX (denmark) / HD
    V Sport Premium HD
    V Sport Urheilu / HD
    ViaPlay (denmark) / HD
    ViaPlay (finland) / HD
    ViaPlay (sweden) / HD
    VOOsport World 1 / HD
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```

Comment: This is pulling the correct date. Thank you. One thing I noticed though when running the output with channels is that it is not scraping the first match and channels showing the first match (Derby County vs Brentford) and it is only scraping the channels from the second match (Watford vs Newcastle) no other match data. Everything else is scraping perfectly. Do you know what could cause these issues? Thanks

Comment: I have ran the code without the following code - channel = match.find_all("td", {"class": "chan_col"})
        for i in channel:
                print(i.get_text().strip())   and it is outputting Derby vs Brentford and Watford vs Newcastle, so I think the issue is with the code I have to output the channels showing each game

Comment: thank you, I also resolved by doing the following 

channel = match.find('div',class_='fLeft_live').text.strip()
print("Channels:", channel)

but I am going to use your method instead. Thanks